# Installing a light with no ground & no accessible outlet box

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, grounding

I'm replacing a light in our bathroom. I unscrewed the old light from the wall and found this:

[image]

The ground wire for the original light fixture was attached to the metal mount that held the light to the wall. The [manual](https://s7d2.scene7.com/s7viewers/html5/eCatalogViewer.html?config=Scene7SharedAssets/Universal_HTML5_eCatalog&asset=homedepotcanada/1001102359_33579-HBC+English-pdf-pdf.pdf) (PDF file) for the new light fixture states that the ground wire for the light should be connected to the ground wire of the outlet box.

I've seen previous questions that ask about grounding and it seems that in the absence of a grounding wire that connecting the light's ground wire to the outlet box would do the job. But here, there's no visible outlet box.

Do I go "digging" in the wall looking for the outlet box, assuming that one must be there? Can I just attach the ground wire to the casing of the new light?

Comment: The old fixture may have been certified to be used as its own junction box - although if that were the case it would have needed some way of clamping the cable and the complete cable (including outer sheath) should have been brought into the box. It's unlikely that there is a box in the wall there, since they're not allowed to be covered over with drywall - but there's probably nothing preventing you from installing one yourself.

Comment: Can you figure out if there's a box behind that drywall, and if not, if the cable back there has a grounding means?